# Activity.requestPermissions vs ActivityCompat.requestPermissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

Runtime permission dialog is shown in Android 6.0 or higher, so `Activity.requestPermissions(...)` which was added in API level 23 makes sense.

But why is there another one (`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)`) to be used for below Android 6.0? Does this show runtime permission request dialog in lower versions?

---

- What is the difference between

  ```
  Activity.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)
  ```

  and

  ```
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode)
  ```
- Which one should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this show runtime permission request dialog in lower versions?

No. There is no such dialog on lower versions. It will simply call your `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method to let you know that you hold the permissions (since, by definition, you already do).

> What is the difference between

`Activity#requestPermissions()` is for apps with a `minSdkVersion` of 23 or higher, or for apps whose developers like calling `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)` to avoid that call on older devices.

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` is for any app, as it "does the right thing" on all supported API levels (back to API Level 14 IIRC).

> Which one should I use?

If your `minSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, feel free to use `Activity#requestPermissions()`. Otherwise, I recommend `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`.

Comment: Will the runtime permission dialog popup, if I use `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` and the device is 6.0 or higher?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala: Yes, assuming that the user has not clicked "don't ask again" for that permission. All `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` does is check `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and call through to `Activity#requestPermissions()` if the device is running Android 6.0+, with fallback behavior if it is not.

Comment: So I assume, `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` is just a lazy way; to get rid of doing another check `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)`

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala: It is a lazy way to skip writing another `SDK_INT` check, plus remembering which version number to check against.

Comment: Actually it is not. `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` is for use in activities that are of the `ActivityCompat` type, while `Activity.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)` is for use in Activities that are of the `Activity` type. my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761651/4605699) has more on that.

Comment: @Pure-Entropy: `ActivityCompat` does not require an `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

> But why is there another one (ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)) to be used for below Android 6.0?

It exists because there are two types of `Acvivity` in Android, `android.app.Activity` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity), and `android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat`[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html).

- `Activity` is for use in devices whose min SDK version is 14 iirc
- `ActivityCompat` is for backwards compatibility (SDK 9 and above). It allows you to have access to supportable new features and Material themes without any of the breaking changes that the new OS versions introduced to achieve the new features and UI.

> Does this show runtime permission request dialog in lower versions?

No. Android 6.0 is the first to show runtime Permission dialogs and as such previous versions of Android cannot show them. That bit of code is actually ignored by previous versions of the OS iirc.

> Which one should I use?

That wholly depends on which type of `Activity` you are using. If your activity is a child of `Activity` then use `Activity.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)`. if you are using a child of `ActivityCompat` however, use `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode)`.

Comment: `ActivityCompat` is not an `Activity`. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.