# ActivityCompat onRequestPermissionsResult() not Called

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I'm trying to write a small class to handle permission checking. Only problem is that onRequestPermissionsResult() never gets called:

```
class PermissionHelper(val activity: Activity) : ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

    interface OnPermissionRequested {
        fun onPermissionResponse(isPermissionGranted: Boolean)
    }

    private var listener: OnPermissionRequested? = null

    fun isPermissionGranted(permission: String) : Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return activity.applicationContext.checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
        return true
    }

    fun requestPermission(permissions: Array<String>,
                          requestCode: Int,
                          listener: OnPermissionRequested) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            this.listener = listener
            activity.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<out String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {

        val isPermissionGranted = grantResults.isNotEmpty() &&
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        listener?.onPermissionResponse(isPermissionGranted)
    }

    companion object {
        const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CALENDAR = 200
        const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR = 201
        const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALENDAR = 101
        const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 102

        const val READ_CALENDAR = Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR
        const val WRITE_CALENDAR = Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
        const val ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    }
}
```

The system dialog to request the permission pops up, but the response is never handled. (i.e. the break point inside onRequestPermissionsResult() is never hit). Nothing is null, and all values are correct.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`onRequestPermissionsResult` will be called on your `Activity`. There is nothing in this code that is going to call the `onRequestPermissionsResult` of your `PermissionHelper`.

You need this in your activity

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                        permissions: Array<out String>,
                                        grantResults: IntArray) {
helper.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use this library for handle permissions:
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

If you don't want to use Dexter library, I suggest use `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` instead of `activity.requestPermissions()`

You can find more info in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761238/5661680

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 you have to use `ActivityResultLauncher` to handle granted (or declined) permissions.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

It is not quite convenient and ask Android team for a new feature proposed here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/293387810